# this has the advanteages of the IQueryable?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, iqueryable, ilist

If I dont' wrong, I can get the data from a database in to ways:

1. First with an IEnumerable:

   `myContext.MyTable.ToList();`
2. With an IQeryable:

   `IQueryable<MyTable> query = myContext.Mytable;`

I know that one of the advantages is that `IQueryable` execute the conditions in the server, so is more efficient and faster that `IEnumerable`.

But In my repository, as I return a List, I would like to know if this:

```
return query.ToList();
```

has the advantages of the `IQueryable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`query.ToList()` is the same like `myContext.MyTable.ToList()`. It returns a collection in memory (the whole database table) and is just an `IEnumerable<T>`, not an `IQueryable<T>`. Every further LINQ operator - for example a `Where` clause - you append, will be performed in memory and not in the database.

If you choose to return `IEnumerable<T>` or `List<T>` from your repository you have to design the repository methods so that you can apply filters, sorting, etc. inside of those methods - for example by passing in filter and sort expressions as parameters into the methods or by creating lots of specialized methods for different use cases - like `GetOrdersByCustomerId`, `GetOrdersByShippingDate`, etc., etc. If you do it outside of and after calling repository methods you will suffer from poor performance.